How would you say "This degree costed me my mental health." in Latin?
When asked "Do you regret being an engineer?", many engineers, including myself, respond with something like: "This degree costed me my mental health.". I was wondering, how would you say that in Latin?
My attempt would be: "Haec diploma mihi mentali sanitate constitit.", by analogy with the phrase "Multo sanguine victoria nobis constitit." ("The victory costed us a lot of blood.").

I feel using the genitive  noun animi can be better than the relational-adj, There are instances of corporis sanitas and at least one animi

I'd be tempted to build something around poena or pretium instead of trying to translate "to cost" directly.

My first thought was doctus [sum] pretio sanitatis [animae], but I'm not positive about that pretio + abl. construction.

@brianpck I don't understand. "Pretio" here is dative or ablative (of "pretium")? Or something else?

I meant to say pretio + gen., e.g. "for the price of X." But I really am not sure that's a good construction--a quick corpus search didn't reveal any obvious parallels.

English tip: the past tense of "cost" is just "cost", not "costed".
